# Trouble Running SQL through VBA - getting Data mismatch and I am not sure how

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form built off of an Outer-Joined Query. I cannot enter data in one field, Syteline_Customer_ID, since after opening the form some calculations are done and that calculated data is then entered into the fields on the other side of this join. I think I have a work around - I was trying to run an Update Query on Form load that would update Tbl_JobTicketHeader with the required data so it will populate when the form is opened. Below is the structure of the related fields and tables:

Tbl_JobTicketHeader (This is the table I am trying to update)

- Access_ID - Autonumber (PK)
- Syteline_Customer_ID - Number [Integer] (FK)  &  (Field trying to update)

It is getting this ID based off of the Customer Name selected on the form. I have created a Query to search for the Customer_Name field in my form as Criteria so I only bring up the related Customer. The table structure looks like:

Tbl_MasterCustomerList (Table Query is built off of)

- Customer_ID - Number [Integer] (PK)  - (Value is assigned from a billing system, cannot autonumber)
- Customer_Name - Short Text

Below is my code:

```
    
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket
    Dim SQL As String

    ID = DLookup("[Customer_ID]", "Qry_CustomerID", "[Customer_Name] = '" & frm("Customer_Name") & "'")
    
    SQL = "UPDATE Tbl_JobTicketHeader " _
        & "SET Syteline_Customer_ID = '" & ID & "'" _
        & " WHERE Access_ID = '" & frm("Part_Number") & "'"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
    
End Sub
```

Any help on this would be very appreciated, I have debug.print'ed out ID and everytime it comes out to an Integer such as 2548, 9999, 5862, etc. I am not quite sure where to go from here or what could be wrong.

Comment: Access_id is a number? If yes, you don't need the single quotes within the `WHERE`clause

Comment: @Ike Thank you, I have made that change. One thing I realized is that this is not set up properly at the Table level. We will have the same parts run for different customers, so this would have to change all the time doing it this way. However if I stored this information with the Sales Orders and used the Customer input off of that form it should work better. At least it will solve my original issue and make it so this one was never created even

Comment: You have the same issue in the `SET` clause which Ike identified in the `WHERE` clause.  In both cases, your SQL statement provides text values for numeric fields.